# How to use for loop to print conditional unique vales for dataframe with numeric columns

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, for-loop

I have to use dataframe with only numeric columns, then use for loop tp print unique values for all columns which have less than 11 unique values. So i was working in this way, but I’ve  got  error.

```
my_dict=numeric.to_dict()
df1=pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
df1.head()

for i in df1:
    if df1[i].nunique()<11:
    print(i,df1[i].unique())

 File "<ipython-input-55-d4180024f73d>", line 3
print(i,df1[i].unique())
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: The error is quite self-explanatory... try adding four spaces before the `print` statement

Answer (score 0):

`print(i,df1[i].unique())` should be indented under `if df[i].nunique()<11:`

```
for i in df1:
    if df[i].nunique()<11:
        print(i,df1[i].unique())
```

Comment: Not necessarily, it should work even if outside the `if` statement

Comment: I have tried in that way too, but  again it gives the same error

Comment: @InesSimonyan it needs to be indented furrther, underneath the `if` statement - see my edited answer

Comment: @inesSimonyan Glad it worked. If any answers help or answer your question, feel free to upvote or accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_dict=numeric.to_dict()
df1=pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
df1.head()

for i in df1:
    if df[i].nunique()<11:
        print(i,df1[i].unique())
```

try using pycharm or spyder ide so that indentations are automatically handled.